# Why does the 'Container Widget Header' appear twice in my grid in my ajax grid?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, blocks, widget

I've built an admin grid following this tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

My issue is that when I use any of the grid controls (pagination or filters), and it uses ajax to get the updated list, then adds a second instance of the text "Some Sample Header Text"?

The text itself comes from the class Ebuynow_Ebnreports_Block_Adminhtml_Shipments_Report

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_blockGroup = 'ebuynow_ebnreports';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_shipments_report';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('ebuynow_ebnreports')
        ->__('Some Sample Header Text');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->removeButton('add');
}
```

In controllers/Adminhtml/Shipments/ReportController, I have these methods responsible for building the initial grid and replying with contents for the ajax option, respectively.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Incoming Shipments'))
        ->_title($this->__('sub title?'));
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/sales');
    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report');
    $this->_addContent($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
}
```

To me, this looks correct, but I am hoping that someone with some magento experience can point out something that could cause this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was caused by the string used in one of the `createBlock()` calls.

To wit, Magento grids consist of a Grid Container class, and a Grid class, which both live in the Block directory of a magento module.

My `createBlock()` strings `ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report` were specifying the grid *container*, when one of them should have been specifying the Grid widget class. Changing the call to `ebuynow_ebnreports/adminhtml_shipments_report_grid` in `gridAction()` fixed the issue.

This was a vexing issue because even when I was calling the container class, the grid itself appeared to work. It would have been better if it just failed until I got the block string correct, so I would have known I was not doing it correctly.