# Custom grid is appearing twice

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, layout, grid

I have a custom grid, when I click on arrow(as under lined), for next or previous records, two grids papers on screen as shown in pic . I have followed [Link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59683/why-does-the-container-widget-header-appear-twice-in-my-grid-in-my-ajax-grid) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927166/magento-adminhtml-custom-module-its-showing-the-grid-twice) not helping me.Don't know where I am doing wrong.
And my controller actions are

```
<?php

class Abc_Xyz_Adminhtml_TypesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Xyz'))->_title($this->__('Types'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('abc_xyz/types');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}

public function editAction() {
    $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('abc_xyz/types')->load($id);

    if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register('xyz_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('abc_xyz/types');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Xyz'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Xyz'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Types'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Types'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('abc_xyz')->__('Type does not exist.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction() {
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $entityId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('entity_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('abc_xyz/types');

        if (!empty($entityId)) {
            $model->load($entityId);    
        } else {
            unset($data['entity_id']);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('abc_xyz')->__('Type Successfully Saved.'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('abc_xyz')->__('Unable to load type.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function deleteAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
        $entityId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('abc_xyz/types');

            $model->setId($entityId)->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Type was successfully deleted.'));

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

}
```

**config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Xyz>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </Abc_Xyz>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <abc_xyz>
                <class>Abc_Xyz_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>abc_xyz_resource</resourceModel>
            </abc_xyz>
            <abc_xyz_resource>
                <class>Abc_Xyz_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <associations>
                        <table>xyz_associations</table>
                    </associations>
                    <types>
                        <table>xyz_types</table>
                    </types>
                </entities>
            </abc_xyz_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <abc_xyz>
                <class>Abc_Xyz_Block</class>
            </abc_xyz>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view>Abc_Xyz_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <abc_xyz>
                <class>Abc_Xyz_Helper</class>
            </abc_xyz>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <abc_xyz_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Abc_Xyz</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
        </abc_xyz_setup>
    </resources>
    <events>
        <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <observers>
                <britvic_extend_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>abc_xyz/observer</class>
                    <method>saveOrderItemData</method>
                </britvic_extend_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>

        <sales_quote_add_item>
            <observers>
                <xyz_data_save_quote>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>abc_xyz/observer</class>
                    <method>saveXyzDataInQuoteItem</method>
                </xyz_data_save_quote>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>

        <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <extra_options>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>abc_xyz/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
                </extra_options>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_load_after>
    </events>
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_email_spspdfexport>
                <label>SPS Export PDF Email</label>
                <file>sps_exportpdf_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_email_spspdfexport>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <sps_orders_pdfexport>
            <schedule>
                <!--<cron_expr>0 23 * 12 *</cron_expr>-->
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>abc_xyz/pdfexports::exportPdfsAndEmail</model>
            </run>
        </sps_orders_pdfexport>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <abc_xyz>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Abc_Xyz</module>
                <frontName>xyz</frontName>
            </args>
        </abc_xyz>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <abc_xyz>
                <file>abc/xyz.xml</file>
            </abc_xyz>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <abc_xyz>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Abc_xyz_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>xyz</frontName>
            </args>
        </abc_xyz>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <xyz_tab>
                <file>xyz.xml</file>
            </xyz_tab>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <xyz_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>abc_xyz/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductXyzData</method>
                </xyz_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

and **adminhtml.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <abc_xyz translate="title" module="abc_xyz">
            <title>Xyz</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <types translate="title" module="abc_xyz">
                    <title>Manage Types</title>
                    <action>xyz/types/</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </types>
                <associations translate="title" module="abc_xyz">
                    <title>Manage Associations</title>
                    <action>xyz/associations/</action>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                </associations>
                <!--<sandbox translate="title" module="abc_xyz">
                    <title>Sandbox</title>
                    <action>xyz/sandbox/</action>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                </sandbox>-->
            </children>
        </abc_xyz>
    </menu>

<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <xyz_configuration>
                                    <title>Xyz</title>
                                </xyz_configuration>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

And **Grid.php**

```
    <?php

class Abc_Xyz_Block_Adminhtml_Types_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('abc_xyz_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('abc_xyz/types')->getCollection();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $helper = Mage::helper('abc_xyz');
    $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

    $showOptionsTypesSelect = Mage::getModel('abc_xyz/types')->showOptionsTypesSelect();

    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Entity ID'),
        'index' => 'entity_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('show_in', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Show In'),
        'index' => 'show_in',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options' => $showOptionsTypesSelect
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

    public function getRowUrl($row) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }

}
```

**Types.php**

```
class Abc_Xyz_Block_Adminhtml_Types extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {

public function __construct() {
    $this->_blockGroup = 'abc_xyz';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_types';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('abc_xyz')->__('Types');
    parent::__construct();
    }

}


app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xyz.xml
```

here I can't see my block, if it is not here how my view is block/grid is being created.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>abc_xyz</name>
                <block>abc_xyz/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>jquery-theme/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery-noconflict.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/xyz.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>xyz.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
                <reference name="order_tab_info">
                    <action method="unsetChild">
                        <name>order_items</name>
                    </action>
                    <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_items" name="order_items" template="xyz/sales/order/view/items.phtml">
                        <action method="addItemRender">
                            <type>default</type>
                            <block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_items_renderer_default</block>
                            <template>xyz/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addColumnRender">
                            <column>qty</column>
                            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_qty</block>
                            <template>sales/items/column/qty.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addColumnRender">
                            <column>name</column>
                            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
                            <template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addColumnRender">
                            <column>name</column>
                            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block>
                            <template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
                            <type>grouped</type>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                </reference>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

I have addedd following under **layout** in **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xyz.xml**

```
    <adminhtml_types_edit_edit>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_edit_tab" name="abc_xyz_types" />
</reference>
```

not working

[image]

Comment: add your code too..

Comment: Please add mgento version on question tag thus user can understand

Comment: @Qaisar Satti that is more complex, I try

Comment: i am asking about `gridAction()`  code

Comment: @@Qaisar Satti  done

Comment: public function gridAction(){....}, is never used

Comment: @ Qaisar Satti can have a look in to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, finally I got it, **public function getGridUrl(){......}** was missing in **Grid.php**
So in grid class

```
class Abc_Xyz_Block_Adminhtml_Types_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
```

add following function,

```
    public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
}
```

after adding this, following function is being called in controller to just refresh the gridview, with out refreshing full page(header+footer+ girdview).

```
public function gridAction() {
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_grid')->toHtml()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is being called twice

```
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types')->toHtml()
```

once in indexAction and second time in gridAction. 
This seems to be the issue.

Comment: As I said in comment **gridAction** is never being called,

Comment: If comment out this portion or whole function, it is working same

Comment: Paste xml code as well.

Comment: xml's are added

Comment: Also add code for xyz.xml that you have mentioned in adminhtml layout config.xml

Comment: xyz.xml file is added

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `gridAction`. It's not displaying twice, but it is breaking.

You must have `block_adminhtml_types_grid` class to show your grid.

Then change `gridAction` as follow:

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_xyz/adminhtml_types_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

This should work.

**UPDATE**

It's also related to your `Types.php` file, however, I don't know how you have written.

Your `Types.php` should be like this:

```
class Abc_Xyz_Block_Adminhtml_Types extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{

    /**
     * Block constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'abc_xyz';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_types';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('abc_xyz')->__('Your Header');

        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, it never comes in gridAction()...

Comment: Can you add your Types.php to your question.

Comment: I think I am doing alright, '$this->_blockGroup = 'types'; should be '  $this->_blockGroup = 'abc_xyz';, if you look into [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar Yes, my mistake, now corrected.